# Global Libraries как зависимость Gradle в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, зависимости

Есть некие глобальные библиотеки заданные в IDEA, могу ли я их подключить в build.gradle? Если я подключаю их вручную, то они сбрасываются при первом же рефреше build.gradle.

Comment: `dependencies {
    compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
}`

Comment: Это понятно, а именно уже заранее добавленные библиотеки в глобальные нельзя подобным способ подключить?